# How to align the top of an item to the center of an activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I need to align the top of an image view to the center of the activity.

If I click and drag it in android studio, i can easily link the center of the image view to the center of the activity. But I need the top if the image view and the center of the activity to link.

How can I do this programmatically? I can't set a margin of 100dp (for example) because it won't work on different screen sizes.

Comment: You can center a empty view in a RelativeLayout, then align top to that empty view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if I understand exactly what do you mean.

I think that you want split you activity layout in two parts with the Imageview that start from the middle of your screen.

I that case you can use easily `PercentRelativeLayout`, here the code:

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:22.2.0'
}
```

layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:src="@color/colorAccent"
            app:layout_paddingTop="50%"
            app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
            app:layout_widthPercent="100%"
        />

        <ImageView
            android:src="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_marginTopPercent="50%"
            app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
            app:layout_widthPercent="100%"
         />

</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

results:

[image: visual example]

P.S: If you prefer you can play with layout weight and get the same result!